# Do a vlookup with pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, replace, vlookup

I am struggling with a vlookup in python.

I have two datasets.

First is called "output_apu_stock1". Here i have quantities and prices, that should be update the second dataset.

Second is called "Angebote_Master_File".

Now, if i run my code, the new dataset "results" contains only the values, that matches. Leads to the problem, that my "Angebote_Master_File" that has originally around 1600 observations, shrinks to around 400 observations.

import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Desktop/output_apu_stock1.csv")

df2 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Desktop/Angebote_Master_File.csv")

results = df2.merge(df1,on="sku")

I got the point, that the final dataset contains only the matched observations (identifier is the column "sku") and drop the others...

I need the merged file containing all observations from the "Angebote_Master_File" without any losses.

Thanks for your help!
Best
Michael

Comment: `results = df2.merge(df1,on="sku", how="left")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

results = df2.merge(df1,on="sku", how="outer")

Comment: thank you for your feedback. It is running well. Furthermore, I would like to skip the observations in the database "results", that are NOT containing in the df2. Maybe you have a tipp?

Comment: Try how = 'left'